# How to set Icon for a secondary activity with BROWSABLE intent filter for android 12?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-manifest

I want open an activity from my app with intentChoser for compass navigation and the problem is that in android 12 icon of this activity is not changed is same as application icon. How to set icon for this activity? 
Bellow is code how icon was set early android:icon="@drawable/ic_compass".

[This ic ic_comapass what we need to show on intentChoser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlOad.png)

[App icon whish is show now in intentChoser for android 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Us7.png)

```
   <activity
        android:name=".ui.compass.CompassActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_compass"
        android:label="@string/compass_navigation_title"
        android:theme="@style/BlueSystemWindows">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="geo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @cliff2310 is more clear now?